# Wordpress posts_per_page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, limit

So, I tried all the "add_filter" things on the whole web to get this right but it doesn't work! It always shows me more than 1 post. What's wrong with my code? Latest WP-Version 4.1.1 and no plugins installed.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');

    if ( !empty($sticky) ) {

    $args = array(
        'post__in' => $sticky,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

    $slider_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) {             
        $slider_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div>
       <!-- here we go -->
    </div>

<?php

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it. This parameter is missing. Wordpress ignores "posts_per_page" by default for sticky posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $sticky,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't play nice with posts_per_page and wp_query.
To fix it you have to use get_query_var, like so:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

And then in your wp_query() you do:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $sticky,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried it but it doesn't work. The funny thing is if I change the number of posts in the settings to 1. wordpress also doesn't care.

Comment: @hhherzblut let me know if it works for you and if it does pls accept my answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry, it didn't show up for me fully, it just said thanks haha. I once had a problem with post__in and paging, can you try without it to see if that's the case ?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your effort.